# MvvmCross calling web service at screensplash

Tags: android, web-services, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm working with MvvmCross and Android. I have to call to webservice in background when SplashScreen is creating, the webservice is created in my PCL. How I can resolve this?

Update
In my MainViewModel I use this:

```
private IQueryService service;
public MainViewModel(IQueryService _service)
{
    service = _service;
}
public override void Start()
{    
    service.InitParametros(result => Query = result.queries);
}
```

this it function call the webservice, but I would like call the webservice from SplashScreen. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: I am using `Device.StartTimer()`, but I believe that won't follow your architecture.

Comment: @Mario Galvan, yes I use other architecture